# How to send json in query parameters in aiohttp in FastAPI

Tags: python, fastapi, aiohttp

Requirement: Sending a json string in query parameters of an API with aiohttp in fastAPI.

Example:

```
some_api/?key1='{"a": "1", "b": "2"}'&key2='{"a": "4", "b": "5"}'
```

I am sending it in params field of aiohttp

```
params = {
    "key1": json.dumps({"a": "1", "b": "2"}),
    "key2": json.dumps({"a": "4", "b": "5"})
}
```

```
async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
     async with session.request(
        method, URL, params=params,
        headers={"content-type": "application/json"}, 
        timeout=5) as response:
      response = await response.json()
      ...
```

This is throwing the following error:

```
unhandled exception occurred while calling the API: 0, message='Attempt to decode JSON with unexpected mimetype: text/html',
```

Comment: The error you're getting is most likely on the line `await response.json()`. The error message `Attempt to decode JSON with unexpected mimetype: text/html` means that you're trying to extract JSON from the response, but the server responded with HTML. Try printing `response.text`, and see what the server is responding with.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to parse the response by giving the correct content type. Try something like this:

```py
response = await response.json(content_type='text/html')
```

Here is specified that the response encoding will raise and exception if the decoding fails https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/client_quickstart.html#json-response-content